# Manually reading in a specific section of a csv file into SAS

Tags: csv, sas

I want to read a csv file into SAS, but I only want to read in part of the file.
For example, I want my first row of data to start at row 18, while I want to read in columns 9, 11, 12, 13, 19, 20, 36.  Is there an efficient way of doing this manually in a data step to read in the file portions I want, or is my best bet just to read in the entire file using the import wizard and just keep the columns of desire?

Comment: this obviously isn't scalable but, why don't you just use excel and delete the rows you dont want and copy just the columns you do want into a new csv then import that

Comment: i know that is the quickest way of doing it, but i was just wondering if it was possible to do it manually.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the row you start with the `DATAROW` option on PROC IMPORT, or `FIRSTOBS` option on a data step input.

You cannot easily read in only select columns, however.  You would have to read in all columns up to the last column you are interested in, and then drop the uninteresting ones.  You could read them all in with a $1 character called "blank" or something (even the same name each time), but you do have to ask for them.

The only workaround would be to write a regular expression to read in your data, in which case you could tell it to look for `,.*?,.*?,` etc. for each skipped column.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use variable names instead of column numbers, this will work. I'd recommend using variable names instead of numbers anyways, as it adds substantive meaning to your code and might help you catch a problem if the input file columns are ever changed.

```
PROC IMPORT datafile = "filename.csv"
    out = data_read (keep = var1 var2 var3)
    dbms = csv
    replace;
    datarow = 18;
RUN;
```